# Приходит не все содержимое письма php почту?

Tags: php, email

Я на писал следующий код для отправки формы на эл. почту, но что то отсылается не все. Данные, которые через ajax приходят есть, но в итоге письмо приходит только с файлом прикрепленным. Буду рад любой помощи!

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['email'])) {
  $to = "pavel.ps2014@yandex.ru";
  $from = "hello@thecbd.ru";
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма на сайте ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "Имя пользователя: ".$_POST['yourName']."\nEmail пользователя ".$_POST['email']."\nТелефон пользователя ".$_POST['tel']."\nВакансия: ".$_POST['select']."\n\nАдрес сайта: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"
 
--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
 
$message";
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'])));
         $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'];
         $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'];
         $filesize = $_FILES['fileFF']['size'];
         $message.="
 
--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"
 
$attachment";
     }
   $message.="

--$boundary--";
 
  if ($filesize < 10000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $_POST['yourName'].', Ваше сообщение отправлено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$message =` и потом снова `$message =`. Не наводит на мысли?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)